# The S3 bucket addressed by the query is in a different region from this cluster

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have just begun my travels on the Redshift road. I am trying to load multiple GZIP files using the copy command and adding a manifest. The S3 bucket and the cluster are both in the same region. My manifest file is a txt file with JSON. Either my syntax is wrong or something else is off. Thanks!

{

```
"entries": [
    
    {
    "url":"s3://abacosdw-load-queue/sales1.txt.gz", "mandatory":true
    },
    {
    "url":"s3://abacosdw-load-queue/sales2.txt.gz", "mandatory":true
    },
    {
    "url":"s3://abacosdw-load-queue/sales3.txt.gz", "mandatory":true
    },
    {
    "url":"s3://abacosdw-load-queue/sales4.txt.gz", "mandatory":true
    }

]
```

}

copy factsales
from 's3://mydw-load-queue/manifest.txt'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/RedshiftS3'
region 'us-west-2'
delimiter '|'
GZIP
manifest

Comment: I’m a bit confused - is the bucket and cluster in the same region or different regions?  Title and body of the question seem to not align on this point.

Comment: Both the cluster and the bucket are in the same region us-west2

Comment: Then you don’t want to use the “region” option. If the bucket is local to the cluster, don’t indicate that it is remote

Answer (score 3):

For each COPY command, do the following:

Replace  with the name of a bucket in the same region as your cluster.

This step assumes the bucket and the cluster are in the same region. Alternatively, you can specify the region using the REGION option with the COPY command.

Refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-run-copy.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the bucket which you have mentioned in the manifest file and the bucket which you are giving in the copy command are in different region please create them in the same region.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following command.

```
copy tablename from output.csv iam_role arn:was:xxxxx REGION 'regionName';
```

Make sure the regionName is in quotes